# ElasticSearch won't return hits on nested query

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a "match" search on a nested "text".
I just started to work with AWS ElasticSearch, so I'm really new to this.

I did my best to follow the documentation, but without luck using the dot syntax "taxonomy.title" :(
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/6.2/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Here's what the part of my query looks like:

```
"match": {"taxonomy.title": {"query": keyword}}
```

and heres a screenshot of my indices:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the "nested" part in your query. Try with:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "taxonomy",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "taxonomy.title": keyword
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```